# Capybara generates tests in /test instead of /spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara, specifications

I try to use Capybara  with rspec. I have installed version 1.1.2.

`rails generate integration_test application`

Unfortunately this is invoking `test_unit` and generates files in `test` instead of `spec`. How could I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generators should generate specs rather than test_unit tests if you have the rspec-rails gem in your development group in your Gemfile, e.g.:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails"
end
```